# Struts2 s:url for a image in s:submit not working

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a JSP with this form:

```
<s:form action="GestionPagos.action">
    <s:hidden key="actividad.id" />
    <s:submit type="image" 
        src="<s:url value ="/Internal Resources/imagenes/alta.png"/>">
    </s:submit>
</s:form>
```

But, when I try to render it in my browser, struts throws this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Private/GestionCalendarios/MenuCalendario.jsp (línea: 144, columna: 1) /Private/GestionCalendarios/ListadoActividadColaboradores.jsp (línea: 51, columna: 64) Tag <s:submit not ended
```

I'm pretty sure that this tag worked before, but after a update, it didn't work anymore.

I can make it work using a classic HTML input tag, or splitting the button into two steps: using the url tag with a variable and then, using in the src field of the submit. But I want to know why isn't working together and what is the correct form of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use struts tags inside the tag attribute. You are also don't need to provide action extension to the action attribute of the `s:form` tag. Rewrite it like

```
<s:url var="imgUrl" value ="/Internal Resources/imagenes/alta.png"/>
<s:form action="GestionPagos">
    <s:hidden name="actividad.id" />
    <s:submit type="image" src="%{#imgUrl}"/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: That is the `#` sympol before the key. It has a special meaning when placed to specify where to get the variable value. You can find more about it [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ognl.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest Struts tags.

Do instead

```
<s:url var="myUrl" value="/Internal Resources/imagenes/alta.png" />
<s:submit type="image" src="%{#myUrl}" />
```